# Running python cgi script Interpreter results differ to browser

Tags: python, iis-7, cgi

I was having difficulty converting a program I made to a cgi script. I suspected it was to do with os.walk so I made a smaller test script to test this.

(I noticed the single \ before the D in the variable loc and tried changing that to a double \ still no change)

Produces no errors cant tell why it doesn't run the for loop with os.walk in the browser.

I tried adding some data into s and run for loop printing of contents of it and that worked fine, but trying to do it on os.walk I can't seem to get it to work. I can't find anything relating to the issue on google or stackoverflow.

Below is the code:

```
import cgi,cgitb,os

loc = "C:\\Users\\wen\Desktop\\sample data\\old py stuff\\"
cgitb.enable(display=1,logdir=loc)

s = []

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print("<html>")
print("<body>")
print("<p>"+loc+"</p>")

for r,ds,fs in os.walk(loc):
    print("<p>omgwtf</p>")
    for f in fs:
        s.append(f) 
for i in s:
    print("<p>"+i+"</p>")

print("</body>")
print("</html>")
```

Took a screenshot, the output in interpreter on the left and browser on right
i.imgur.com/136y1Yq.jpg

webserver is running iis7

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've solved the problem, I needed to give the folders permissions for 'Authenticated users'.